# Progress dialog's IncrementProgressBy is not working as expected

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, progressdialog

Before reaching the max value, I see progress dialog seek bar goes to 100% of the line and it waits at 100% untill it reaches max value

Here is the code I start the Progress dialog:

```
public void ShowProgressBar(string title, string message, int max, int progress)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity);
            dialog.SetTitle(title);
            //dialog.SetMessage(message);
            dialog.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Horizontal);
            dialog.Max = max;
            dialog.Progress = 0;
            dialog.Show();
        });
    }
```

Here I'm updating progress as:

```
public void UpdateProgressBar(string message, int max, int progress)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            if (dialog != null)
            {
                  dialog.IncrementProgressBy(progress);
                  dialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                  dialog.SetCancelable(false);
            }
        });  
    }
```

Max value is 18, when I debug, when the progress value is 12 or 13, I see seek bar loads full and wait at 100% till the progress value is 18.

My requirement is to show 100% with the flow of progress value.

Comment: I test your provide code, it run normally, you can see this GIF,https://imgur.com/a/Y3xpHat, can you provide a demo to re-produce this issue?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT  Sorry for late reply. I changed dialog.IncrementProgressBy(progress); to dialog.progress = progress; in updateProgressBar method and it's working exactly as required.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your sharing, please post your solution as an answer and accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered.